# JavaScript's click()

Tags: javascript, forms

Some bad browsers do not allow doing the following:

```
<input type="file" id="file_input" />

document.getElementById('file_input').click();
```

Can we somehow learn if the click is allowed or not?

Comment: I think the answer is going to be *use jQuery*: `$("#file_input").click();`

Comment: jQuery is not that powerful =lol

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're after, but you can check if it's there before calling like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById('file_input').click;
if(c) c();
```

Though, there's probably a much better way to go about what you're doing....I say this because most browsers will block you trying to auto-open a file dialog ([though IE will allow it](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nHY9K/)...which is where all these non-standard `.click()` functions started).

Comment: Firefox and Opera have `.click()` anyways, even though it doesn't seem to open the file choose dialog. And I wouldn't say most browsers; only those two prevent auto-opening the dialog that way.

Comment: Chrome, Safari, and IE allow it.

Comment: @Spa - They allow you to `.click()` yes, but not open the file dialog, check it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nHY9K/

Comment: @Spa - I don't understand...define "doesn't work"?  The above code just prevents an error, it doesn't bypass a browser security feature that disallows you from auto-opening the "choose file" dialog.

Comment: How would we learn if the click is allowed or not with what you suggested? Re-read the question.

Comment: @Spa - It's always allowed, *what it does* is a different question, you can't do much with a file dialog specifically, for (hopefully) pretty obvious security reasons.